# Reading fixture using typescript return undefined in other steps

Tags: typescript, cypress

I want to read data from json file and use it in my typescript test file. therefor i have created a beforeeach

```
describe(`test`, () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.fixture("testdata").then(function (data: any) {
      cy.log(`reading fixture file`);
      this.data = data;
      cy.log(data.firstName);
      this.firstname = data.firstName;
    });
  });
  it(`testdata should be read`, () => {
    // the value of firstname is undefined at this point
  });
});
```

I do not understand why and how i could read the data correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `function() {` instead of `() => {` when referencing properties of `this`.

Examples shown here [Sharing Context](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Sharing-Context), but it's not just limited to aliases - any reference to `this` needs to follow this rule (both the beforeEach() callback and the it() callback).